# Ruby/Ruby on Rails vs PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We do not get many projects in Ruby. We are focused only on PHP so far. As a web development agency, are we missing an important channel of revenue due to our unopened nature with Ruby and Ruby on Rails?
If we start doing some local projects in Ruby, is it possible to open another revenue channel? Is it wise to ask PHP developers to learn Ruby too?

With our expertise in search, we can promote Ruby and reach people who do Ruby projects, but are they a big crowd?

Comment: Isn't this a business question, not a programming question?

Answer (score 8):

I would say it depends entirely on your customer base. If you are building website for companies that like to dictate the technology stack, then yeah, you could probably open up another revenue channel by offering ruby development.

However, I believe that most of the time customers don't care too much about what technology you use - they just want the job done on time and under budget. In these cases offering Ruby probably won't do much for you other than widen your horizons/options (which I believe is a good thing, but not necessarily tied to revenue).

Comment: You are right, customers do not mind technology, as long as we meet their requirements within their budget.

Comment: Indeed, your typical customer won't (shouldn't have to) care about the technology you use, as long as you get the job done well, within the budget. The customer should be able to work with you on the goals and requirements, and trust you in choosing the right tools for the job.

Answer (score 4):

At this point, I think that Ruby on Rails is bigger with people that are building things themselves than it is with people that are paying other people to build things.  That may change over time.

Do you feel like you are being hired now because of your PHP skills or on your general reputation as a web dev agency?  Most customers probably do not care.

Use what makes you most productive.  In your shoes, I would certainly be giving RoR a good look as I like it better myself.  If you find that RoR makes your job easier then use it.  If not, maybe do not bother.  There are many Rails inspired MVC frameworks for PHP though which you could look at as well.

There is certainly more buzz around Ruby on Rails these days so it may make you look more plugged in sometimes.

I do not see a problem with expecting devs to learn it.  Your better devs would probably love the opportunity.  With the world going Agile though, it probably makes sense to let the devs choose the technology unless there is a market-driven reason to change.

Comment: I agree. Most Rails apps in in-house apps or SaaS.

Comment: We speak a lot about our skill sets in our site, But mostly customers do not read. Instead they prefer to confirm through Email if we are developing database driven websites/ applications. PHP too have many MVC frameworks, we use Codeigniter very much. Based on all these cleaver answers, I believe we do not have to worry about a new technology now, as we are mostly project/client driven and not technology driven. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Ruby on Rails and PHP are both capable of doing the same kind of things. Some people just find it easier or more pleasant with RoR. Unless you find you're losing gigs specifically because you want Rails, I wouldn't worry about it as a "channel of revenue" — it seems unlikely to me, since most non-developers don't have any idea what "the PHP" is anyway.

It is probably worth checking out just to see what your options are. You might find it works out well for you. But the benefits will generally be on the development side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Focus is good and diversity is good. It is sort of a "how long is a piece of string".

1. PHP is a strong maturing language, widely used, supported, and easy to learn. Ruby on the other hand is quite different, it involves a lot more command line calls.
2. Ruby is highly praised and there is quite a good solution. It is a lot quicker to make applications.
3. CodeIgniter / Zend are PHP frameworks which might be worth looking at.
4. Can you afford to train people in a new language?

Dale

Answer (score 0):

cakePHP might be a good fit for your team.